# How to query Sql Server data from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sql-server-2005

For the following scenario:

A JavaScript client application sends a JSON query to a webservice. Simplified query example:

```
{
    table: "orders",
    filter: {
        date: "2011-01-25"
    }
}
```

The webservice compiles the request into a SQL query and executes it on SQL Server.
The webservice returns the result of the query in JSON format.

I need the simplest way (technology stack) to implement the webservice. It should run under Windows Server and IIS 6 and work with SQL Server 2005. I prefer a dynamic language so that the changes in the data definition should not be kept in sync manually.

Answer (score 1):

Check out these two:

- [WCF RIA Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707344%28VS.91%29.aspx)
- [Dynamic Data Domain Service](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pranav_rastogi/archive/2010/05/22/using-domain-service-with-asp-net-dynamic-data.aspx)

It will be easier for you to use jQuery on the client side, because it's able to parse JSON for you. And if you do a search on Google aboout either of them you will find enough resources to get you started.

You will have some more configuration to do on your outdated IIS6 machine, but I suppose it should work just as well. I can't guarantee but check the web. And if at all possible upgrade to IIS7. It's about time you do...

Comment: JSON is a subset of javascript, so there is no need to parse JSON in javascript.  Bu jQuery still rocks ;)

Comment: @Ivan: JSON strings aren't objects just yet. You have to convert them.

Comment: Well as he uses it just for AJAX it is safe enough jsut to use eval. However I still fully agree with you. jQuery is much easier to use for send and receive data.